# How to convert datatype of multiple columns at once based on pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with columns like as shown below

[image]

I haven't provided dummy data as the issue is nothing to do with data.

I am trying to change the datatype of `time` related columns from `object` to `datetime` type

This is the code that I tried

```
for c in df1.columns:
   print(type(c))
   if c.contains('time'):
      print(c)
      pd.to_datetime(df[c])
```

But I get an error message that

> 'str' object has no attribute 'contains'

However **when I use `c.endswith('time')**, it all works fine as shown below

[image]

I tried with `contains` and `contain` but it doesn't work. Am I making any blunder? How can one attribute like `endswith` work but not `contains`

Comment: Iterating of `pd.DataFrame.columns` returns `str`, which does have `endswiths` but not `contains`, which is a method of `pandas` str accessor. Besides, I think what you want is `df.filter(like='time')`.

Comment: Would you mind writing it as an answer, for me to mark as solution?

Comment: sure. added some example snippet for demonstration :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating of `pd.DataFrame.columns` returns `str`, which does have `endswiths` but not `contains`, which is a method of `pandas` str accessor:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'btime', 'timec', 'timedtime', 'e'])
for c in df.columns:
    print(type(c), hasattr(c, 'endswith'), hasattr(c, 'contains'))
```

Output:

```
# type    endswith contains
<class 'str'> True False
...
```

Also, [`df.filter(like='time').columns`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html):

```
Index(['btime', 'timec', 'timedtime'], dtype='object')
```

returns just as desired:

> **like** : string
>   Keep labels from axis for which “like in label == True”.

Comment: It works. Will accept the answer atfer time limit. Upvoted already